# How to export an image from Photoshop to PDF while preserving the exact size?

Tags: pdf, adobe-photoshop, export, image-editing

There used to be a PDF export option in Photoshop, but it's gone in CS4.

What replaced it is Bridge, however no matter what I do, Bridge ends up resizing my image. The physical dimensions (cm/inches) in the final PDF are not what they are in Photoshop.

Any tips on exporting an image without messing up its size?

(Clarification: I want the final PDF to contain a page of the size I specify, with a white background, and my image positioned somewhere on this page such that the image width/height in cm is exactly the same in the PDF as it was in Photoshop.)

Comment: What about using PDFcreator? Print to PDF from the printing menu in PS (and print the PDF ?)

Comment: @Shiki that might be good enough, thanks. Didn't occur to me for some reason, even though I often use it from other programs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose File, Save As, and then choose Photoshop PDF as the type.  No need to go through Bridge.